# Copy array to another array in same collection

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I want to copy items from `admin` to `newAdmins` if it does not exist in the `newAdmins`

**Before:**

```
[
  {
    _id: "60801199bf57265ed8b786bc",
    admins: [
     "Kenny"
     "Abu"
     "Raj"
    ],
    newAdmins: [
     "Kenny"
     "Abu"
    ]
  }
]
```

**After:**

```
[
  {
    _id: "60801199bf57265ed8b786bc",
    admins: [
     "Kenny"
     "Abu"
     "Raj"
    ],
    newAdmins: [
     "Kenny"
     "Abu"
     "Raj"
    ]
  }
]
```

Searched online but could not find a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

One option is:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      newAdmins: {
        $setUnion: [
          "$newAdmins",
          "$admins"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
], 
{multi: true})
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xTofTQ7V3kb)

Comment: i run it says `fail to run update: update document must contain key beginning with '$'`

Comment: Is it working for you on the playground example? Did you copy the `$set` part?

Comment: playground not working, ya it has the $set part, i just click on the playground example link and click run

Comment: You are right. It was my bad. Updated it now